# Combining two data frames

Tags: r

I have two data frames from a study, datlighton and datlightoff, They both have roughly the same data since what separates the observations is that off takes place before midnight and on takes place after. I need to combine them into a single data frame called datlight but I'm not sure how to do it. I've tried using cbind and merge but I'm new to R and I don't quite understand how to make it do exactly what I want. When I try `merge(datlighton,datlightoff)` it gives me a data frame with all the column names but none of the rows. This is [datlighton](http://file:///Users/brittabergren/Desktop/Ecology/Term%20Paper/Term%20Paper%20Work/datlighton.html) and [datlightoff](http://file:///Users/brittabergren/Desktop/Ecology/Term%20Paper/Term%20Paper%20Work/datlightoff.html), I converted it to an html since I don't know to upload them as dataframes from R. Basically I just need to put all the rows from one frame into the other and have them match up with the appropriate column name.

Comment: Links to files on your desktop are not going to work. Please create some example data using `dput(head(datlighton))` and the equivalent for the other data.

Comment: those links are to the files on your computer. can you paste in the results of `dput(head(datlighton))` and `dput(head(datlightoff))` instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
 a=data.frame(a=4:6,b=2:4,d=7:9)
 f=data.frame(a=4:7,b=2:5,c=9:6,d=0:3,e=6:9)
 Result = merge(a,f,by="row.names",all=TRUE)

 a
    a b d
  1 4 2 7 
  2 5 3 8
  3 6 4 9

  f
    a b c d e
  1 4 2 9 0 6
  2 5 3 8 1 7
  3 6 4 7 2 8
  4 7 5 6 3 9

  Result
    Row.names a.x b.x d.x a.y b.y c d.y e
  1         1   4   2   7   4   2 9   0 6
  2         2   5   3   8   5   3 8   1 7
  3         3   6   4   9   6   4 7   2 8
  4         4  NA  NA  NA   7   5 6   3 9

  Result[is.na(Result)] <- 0
  Result
    Row.names a.x b.x d.x a.y b.y c d.y e
  1         1   4   2   7   4   2 9   0 6
  2         2   5   3   8   5   3 8   1 7
  3         3   6   4   9   6   4 7   2 8
  4         4   0   0   0   7   5 6   3 9
```